# How to check ReturnValue parameter for null using ODP.NET?

Tags: c#, odp.net

I have an Oracle function that returns number, and sometimes null (on exceptions).
I am calling this function from C# using ODP.NET v2.
How can I check if returned value is null ?

I checked the parameter while debugging when returned value was null, and this is what it shows:

[image]

IsNull property is private, and comparing parameter Value to *null* or *DBNull.Value* **always returns false**..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(command.Parameters[...].value == null)
```

Comment: it always returns false, even when oracle function actually returns null

Comment: @Nina what is the object type?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Oracle function returns number, or null.  The parameter is defined as Int32. The command parameter value is (object).

Answer (score 0):

or this :
if (command.Parameters[...].value is DBNull)

Comment: it always returns false, even when oracle function actually returns null